# Homomorphisms of a Semidirect Product

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product, group-schemes

Suppose $G_1=N_1\rtimes H_1$, $G_2=N_2\rtimes H_2$ are semidirect products of (not necessarily finite or abelian) groups. Suppose $f:N_1\to N_2$ and $g: H_1\to H_2$ are group homomorphisms.

How can we use this data to construct a morphism $h:G_1\to G_2$? The obvious map $(f,g)$ doesn't work since it does not preserve multiplication. It seems one needs to cleverly choose how to glue these such that in the end the necessary diagram commutes, but it is continuing to evade me.

Context is the following: suppose $N$ and $H$ are affine group schemes where $H$ acts on $N$ via group automorphisms. I wish to show that $G(R):=N(R)\rtimes H(R)$ yields an affine group scheme. In particular, I am struggling to see where $G$ takes morphisms of $k$-algebras $R\to S$.

Comment: There is no reason such an $h$ should exist in general (one that restricts to $f$ and $g$ on the appropriate subgroups, that is). Presumably you need some sort of compatibility condition between $f$ and $g$ relating the actions of $H_i$ on $N_i$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hm, this is interesting. Perhaps I do not demand that $h$ restricts to $f$ and $g$. My context is the following: if I have two affine group schemes $H$ and $N$ with one acting on the other as group automorphisms, I want to show that we have an affine group scheme $G$ for which $G(R)=N(R)\rtimes H(R)$. But I fail to see how this is even a functor. Given a morphism of $k$-algebras $R\to S$, what is the corresponding morphism $G(R)\to G(S)$? If one cannot glue the data of $H(R)\to H(S)$ and $N(R)\to N(S)$, I am at a loss, frankly.

Comment: In that setup the hypothesis that $H$ acts on $N$ *as a group scheme* provides the desired compatibility. Alternatively you can construct the semidirect product group scheme explicitly as a Hopf algebra and then check that it has the appropriate functor of points.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, I see, my bad. The naturality condition gives me what I want on the nose. Thank you again for the help. If you post even that hint as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer: in the setup you describe there's an extra compatibility coming from the naturality of the action map $H(-) \times N(-) \to N(-)$, and this extra compatibility lets you write down $h$ componentwise in the obvious way.